# Can an MSDE 2000 database be deplolyed to SQL Server 2000?

Tags: migration, sql-server-2000, compatibility, msde, msde2000

I am developing a Web Application using SQL Server 2005 for the database, but will need to deploy the database to SQL Server 2000 in the production environment.

We don't have a license for SQL Server 2000 (we've only got for 2005), and I've come accross a range of incompatibilites and issues when migrating the DB from 2005 to 2000.

I was hoping I could switch my development DB over to MSDE 2000, and then depoy it to SQL Server 2000 when in production.

Will this work? Is MSDE compatible with SQL Server 2000? How easy is it to migrate from one to the other? Is it as simple as a backup and restore?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

And it is as simple as a backup and restore.

Caveat: be sure both server and dev machine are running the same service pack. IIRC, that could matter.

MSDE does have some feature limitations, but as long as you aren't using features only supported on the full server version, you should be fine.